# AWS EC2のSSH接続に失敗する

Tags: aws, ssh

使用OS: Windows 10

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/first-login-to-ec2-linux/
https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aws-beginner-ec2-ssh/

上記の2リンクを参考にして、EC2へのSSH接続を試みましたが、失敗してしまいます。

エラーメッセージ（TeraTermの）は「認証に失敗しました。」なので、1つ目のリンク先の末尾にある「認証に失敗している」の内容が該当しそうです。
（ちなみに「ネットワーク的に通信できない」にある、「EC2のパブリックIP/パブリックDNS名が間違っている」や「セキュリティグループで通信が許可されていない」などは、EC2のインスタンスとセキュリティグループ設定を確認しましたが該当しなさそうです。

一体何が原因なのでしょうか。

（Amazon Linuxのため初期ユーザ名はec2-userです。秘密鍵についてはインスタンス作成時の.pemファイルを適用しており、自分のPC上に1つしかないため間違ってることは考えにくいです。）

Comment: 本当にEC2のインスタンス作成時に正しくその鍵を登録していますか？確認してみてください。インスタンスの説明に「キーペア名」が表示されているはずです。（おそらく大丈夫かとは思います。）また、Windows 10にはOpenSSHがバンドルされています。コマンドプロンプトやPowershellを開いて `ssh` と打ってみてください。もしコマンドが見つからない場合は[設定やPowershellでインストールできます](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) 。こちらでMacやLinuxなどからSSHするのと同様に接続できるはずなので、同様のエラーが出るか確認してみてください。

Comment: エラーメッセージだけでなく、[ログ](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/setup/teraterm-ssh.html)も確認してください。

Comment: @hinaloe 新しく別のインスタンスを作り直した所、無事にSSH接続に成功しました。

鍵に関しては、質問時に設定したインスタンスのものと同一のものを設定しました。
インスタンスの作成はこれで2つ目なので、質問時に設定したインスタンスの鍵の他に鍵は存在しないため、鍵の設定に関して間違っていたのかは疑問でした。

他に原因があるとすると、[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/70341?link=qa_related_pc_sidebar) のページで紹介されている事象などが原因だったのかもしれません。振り返る機会が出来た時に追求したいと思います。